# Is there any way to get the content from doc file php

Tags: php

my Q is there any way to get the word count or the content of Microsoft word file in **PHP**?

Comment: yes, so what's the real question?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try http://phpword.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. consider the contents of the word document a string, and write a word count function to count the words in that string. There is code for such a task here: http://www.reconn.us/count_words.html

Importing the .doc file might be a harder task. You can do it by implementing a com object. There might  be a simpler way, though.

Comment: The task of extracting plain text from a Word document is left as exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: Yeah. Is there nothing in the php api for this? Seems strange. There'd have to be a library to do it somewhere. Piece of cake in asp.net, of course.